# Use @WebMvcTest without @MockBean in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I am working on an assignment where a test case is already provided and I cannot change it in any sense whatsoever.

I have created a simple web project using spring boot whose controller looks like :

**Controller.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class Controller {

    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public Controller(final PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<PersonResponse> testPerson(@RequestBody PersonRequest personRequest) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(personService.clearPastHistory((personRequest)), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And the Service layer is :

**Service.java**

```
@Service
public class PersonServiceImplementation implements PersonService {
    @Override
    public PersonResponse clearPastHistory(PersonRequest requestDTO) {
        //business logic here
    }
```

**ControllerTest.java**

Here, the BASE_REQUEST is a json string which acts as an input from the user.

```
@WebMvcTest(Controller.class)
class ControllerTest {

    private static final MockHttpServletRequestBuilder REQUEST_BUILDER =
        request(HttpMethod.POST, "/person")
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .accept(APPLICATION_JSON);

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void callCorrectEndpoint() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(REQUEST_BUILDER.content(BASE_REQUEST))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

Now the issue is I cannot build the project without using

```
@MockBean
private PersonService personService;
```

in my test class.

and if I am using this and submitting to an online portal, the automated tests in the portal are failing with an error that `Testcase was modified`.

Is there a way possible to achieve this without modifying the test case at all ?
Would be highly thankful for any help.

Comment: It is dangerous to call ur controller Controller x very easy to import springs controller instead in other classes

Comment: Can you potentially add an `@TestConfiguration` bean alongside your test class?

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- can you please explain a bit how to do it ? I cannot add this annotation on the existing test class.

Comment: I wonder how this test is working without service class is being mocked @newLearner

Comment: @Deadpool this was working initially because I was provided with an empty controller. When I added the code as per my requirement it started failing saying I cannot modify the test :(

Comment: The error message you are saying is confusing to me, can you add the error message with stack trace in the question ? @newLearner

Comment: @Deadpool could you please suggest if it is possible to achieve this without modifying the test class at all ?